# Unity 3D One Way Wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game in Unity 3D, and I'm looking for a one-way wall. In Unity 2D, there is a simple one way platform (PlatformEffector2D) that can only allow a player to go one way. I couldn't find something similar for 3D. Is there something simple like the PlatformEffector2D, but for Unity 3D?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You're welcome :)

Comment: (this is a hint that your question is poorly asked and here's a good link on how to [learn to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Sorry. I updated the question. I'm looking for something like the 2D PlatformEffector2D but for Unity 3D.

Answer (score 1):

Try to have a collider at the start of the way when its trigered disabled the rotation of the player. and then use function

```
Vector3.RotateTowards
```

to your desired direction.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can check which side of the wall the player is in by finding the position of the player and the wall. If he is on the desired side for passage through the wall, make the wall on a separate collision layer than the player. If it is on the the other side, then make the player and wall on the same collision layer.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly if you are looking for a one way wall. You might want to look into using a raycast. Project a raycast in the direction where the character should be able to walk through the wall. If that raycast hits the object then remove or set the collider to be a trigger.